# Distribute reports when a certain field is used

Tags: business-intelligence, cognos

We are using a Code and if that code is used we want a report to automatically send out.
Sales Code (if this sales code is used send out report) 
This is used for a check method to ensure that sales code is not used inproperly.

Not sure how to do do this in cognos.

Thanks in advance,

Nathan

Comment: You mentioned sales, does this mean the report needs to be run once daily 
Or this information needs to be sent out minutes after the potential issue is detected?

Comment: Needs to be sent out minutes after the potential issue is detected.

Answer (score 0):

Event Studio might be the way to go here.

Use IBM® Cognos® Event Studio to notify decision-makers in your organization of events as they happen, so that they can make timely and effective decisions.

You create agents that monitor your organization's data to detect occurrences of business events. An event is a situation that can affect the success of your business. An event is identified when specific items in your data achieve significant values. Specify the event condition, or a change in data, that is important to you. When an agent detects an event, it can perform tasks, such as sending an e-mail, adding information to the portal, and running reports.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_es.doc/c_event_studio.html